# nodejs child_process spawn command input file

Tags: node.js

I would like to run the following code in nodejs

```
$ ./a.out < inputfile.txt
```

So I wrote the following code.

```
var run = spawn('./a.out', ['< input.txt']);
var run = spawn('./a.out < input.txt');
```

I tried this, but it did not work.

What I want to do is to input `input.txt` in`a.out`

how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `<` (redirection) is a shell construct, you need to run your command line with a shell. That's what [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) is for:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('./a.out < inputfile.txt', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('exec error:', err);
  }
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
});
```